# How to evalute $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1} dx$?

Tags: analysis

I want to know how to calculate $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1} dx$, I want to use the contour integration,so I use $\frac{1}{t}$ subsitute $x$ , and get $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln t}{t^2+t-1} dx$, then I evalute $\int_C \frac{\ln z}{z^2-z-1} dz$, I need some advice about how to do the integral.

Answer (score 1):

> I will show another method because I do not really know how to apply contour integration in this case.

Let's find:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Now, we can perform partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1}=\frac{2\ln x}{\sqrt{5}\left(2x-\sqrt{5}-1\right)}-\frac{2\ln x}{\sqrt{5}\left(2x+\sqrt{5}-1\right)}\tag2$$

So, we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\left\{\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{2x-\sqrt{5}-1}\space\text{d}x-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{2x+\sqrt{5}-1}\space\text{d}x\right\}\tag3$$

Let's solve a general case:

$$\mathscr{I}_\text{n}:=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{2x+\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\tag4$$

Let's substitute $\text{u}=2x+\text{n}$, this gives:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{I}_\text{n}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(\text{u}-\text{n}\right)-\ln 2}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(\text{u}-\text{n}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}-\ln 2\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{1}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}\right\}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(\text{u}-\text{n}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}-\ln 2\cdot\left[\ln\left|\text{u}\right|\right]_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\right\}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(\text{u}-\text{n}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}-\ln 2\cdot\left(\ln\left|2+\text{n}\right|-\ln\left|\text{n}\right|\right)\right\}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(\text{u}-\text{n}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}-\ln\left(2\right)\cdot\ln\left|\frac{2+\text{n}}{\text{n}}\right|\right\}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(\text{u}-\text{n}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}-\ln\left(2\right)\cdot\ln\left|\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1\right|\right\}
\end{split}\tag5
\end{equation}

Now, if we can rewrite:

$$\frac{\ln\left(\text{u}-\text{n}\right)}{\text{u}}=\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{\text{u}}{\text{n}}\right)}{\text{u}}+\frac{\ln\left(-\text{n}\right)}{\text{u}}\tag6$$

So, we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(\text{u}-\text{n}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}
&=\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{\text{u}}{\text{n}}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}+\ln\left(-\text{n}\right)\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{1}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}\\
\\
&=\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{\text{u}}{\text{n}}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}+\ln\left(-\text{n}\right)\cdot\left[\ln\left|\text{u}\right|\right]_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\\
\\
&=\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{\text{u}}{\text{n}}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}+\ln\left(-\text{n}\right)\cdot\left(\ln\left|2+\text{n}\right|-\ln\left|\text{n}\right|\right)\\
\\
&=\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{\text{u}}{\text{n}}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}+\ln\left(-\text{n}\right)\cdot\ln\left|\frac{2+\text{n}}{\text{n}}\right|\\
\\
&=\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{\text{u}}{\text{n}}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}+\ln\left(-\text{n}\right)\cdot\ln\left|\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1\right|
\end{split}\tag7
\end{equation}

Let's substitute $\text{v}=\frac{\text{u}}{\text{n}}$, this gives:

$$\int_\text{n}^{2+\text{n}}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{\text{u}}{\text{n}}\right)}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}=\int_1^{\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1}\frac{\ln\left(1-\text{v}\right)}{\text{v}}\space\text{dv}\tag8$$

Now, let's write:

$$\int_1^{\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1}\frac{\ln\left(1-\text{v}\right)}{\text{v}}\space\text{dv}=-\int_1^{\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1}-\frac{\ln\left(1-\text{v}\right)}{\text{v}}\space\text{dv}\tag9$$

Which is a special integral, namely the dilogarithm:

$$\int_1^{\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1}\frac{\ln\left(1-\text{v}\right)}{\text{v}}\space\text{dv}=-\left[\text{Li}_2\left(\text{v}\right)\right]_1^{\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1}=\text{Li}_2\left(1\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1\right)\tag{10}$$

And $\text{Li}_2\left(1\right)$ has a known value, namely $\text{Li}_2\left(1\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

So, we can write:

$$\mathscr{I}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1\right)+\ln\left(-\frac{\text{n}}{2}\right)\cdot\ln\left|\frac{2}{\text{n}}+1\right|\right\}\tag{11}$$

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the funtion $Li_2(v)$ ?